# How can I access HttpContext out side the controller using MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to access HttpContext outside the Controller? I am trying to use this code in static class and HttpContext should be same HttpContext that using in MVC Controller

HttpContext.Response.AddCacheItemDependencies()

Comment: This is poor practice. Either pass your values as parameters (or inject your custom context) or instantiate a class that is maintained with some form of application cache (Session for example).. Using static classes with HttpContext might leave you susceptible to session hijacking

Comment: My class is already registered as Singleton using Autofac

builder.RegisterType<MyClass>().As<IMyClass>().SingleInstance();

So is there any other way to access HttpContext inside the MyClass ?